# Add single quotes when encoding data in php

Tags: php

I have a array :

```
$arr = ['name', 'age', 'address'];
$impString = implode(',',$arr); 
// result : "name','age','address"
```

The result I want: `"'name','age','address'"`

Help me please.

Comment: So you simply want to concatenate an additional single quote to the front and back of the result ... and that is seriously something you need to _ask_ about?

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = ['name', 'age', 'address'];
echo "\"'".implode("','", $arr)."'\"";
```

with this code I added " and ' at the beginning and at the end (for the " I used the \ to escape the " char), then with implode I included the ',' between each item of array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```html
<?php
    
$arr = ["name", "age", "address"];
$impString = "'".implode("','",$arr)."'";
echo $impString;
```